# Hover over a hidden element to show it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, events

Is there any way to hover over an element that's already hidden. I am trying to mimic what Steam does with their arrow navigation on their home page. You'll notice that when you first get to the page, there are no arrows showing:

[image]

Then when you hover over the area where there should be an arrow, it shows itself:

[image]

I've tried setting my divs that contain the arrow images to `display: none` and have also tried `visibility: hidden` but neither seems to work with the hover or mouseover methods in jQuery. I would have thought `visibility: hidden` would make it work, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Is there any other way I can hide these divs from the start but still be able to have hover events work on them?

Comment: I don't think the hover events ARE on the hidden elements.

Comment: on the steam site opacity:0 is used

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Set it to zero opacity instead:

```
$('#blah').hover(function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(1,1);
},function() {
    $(this).fadeTo(1,0);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/bzaax/

Comment: Brilliant solution. I had this element that I completely hidden and my hover event won't respond because it can't see the element. But with opacity set to zero, the element is just there waiting to be triggered.

Answer (score 12):

You cannot hover over an invisible element or an undisplayed element. You can hover over a visible element and then use that to show a different previously hidden element. Or you can hover over a transparent element and make it opaque.

[**Here is an example of the opacity technique using just CSS, it would also work with jQuery's hover.**](http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/cVDwJ/)

**CSS:**

```
#it {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 500px;
    height:500px;
}

#it:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[**Here is an example of showing one element when another is hovered over:**](http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/7M3H7/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="me">Hover over me to display something else</div>
<div id="else">Something else</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#me").hover(function(){
   $("#else").show();
},function(){
   $("#else").hide();
});
```

Comment: opacity values higher than 1 are "clamped" to 1
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/opacity

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`.fadeTo`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) jQuery method to change the opacity of the element on hover state.

The jQuery site contains an example but something like this should suffice

```
$("element").hover(//On Hover Callback
                   function() {$(this).fadeOut(100);} ,
                   //Off Hover Callback 
                   function() {$(this).fadeIn(500);})
```

From the [jQuery Hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) page.

Comment: the .fadeTo() method worked great along with setting the opacity to 0 initially. The .fadeOut() and .fadeIn() methods did not work though...

Answer (score 4):

You could set it to `opacity: 0`.

In order to make it cross-browser you probably would like to do it with jQuery tho.

Comment: If you don't use jQuery, also include in the css style 
filter:alpha(opacity=0);
 for ie8 and older.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by using an alternate hit-test div, such that it has no content, but when hovered over it shows the "arrow" div. When the "arrow" div (or the hit-test div) is exited, then the "arrow" div would be hidden once again.

Alternatively, you could use the same div for the hit-test and the "arrow", such that a background image is used for the visual elements of the div. When hovered, you could instruct the image's offset to be set to a position which would show the "arrow". When exited, you would set the offset of the background to a position where the arrow image would not longer be shown.

And, finally, if the content will always be in the same position as the hit-test area, you could set the opacity of the div to zero, and toggle accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the opacity of the elements to 0. That would allow them to receive the hover events (actually mouseenter and mouseleave), but as a practical matter, make them invisible to users.