# Show hide multiple div

Tags: jquery, accordion

I have multiple div tags which is line up like ordered list and show only titles when page onload.

I want to show hidden area but
1 - Hidden text expand/collapse when OnMouseOver and OnMouseOut
2 - Hidden text stay visible when click on that div

i really appreciate for any help, i have spend my whole day to find something useful but non-of them worked.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a accordion like structure.. Please check this [**`Fiddle`**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/soundar24/X833W/1/) , this might helps you..

Comment: dear @soundar-r. Thank you again for wonderful code but unfortunately your code makes everything( esp. images) 150px height inside of child div. Also i have checkbox in the parent div moves about 150px below when i move my mouse over checkbox. Any idea how to fix this? Because code works excellent if there is ONLY text in it(both parent and child div)

Comment: I have updated the structure as your wish. Please check [**here**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/soundar24/6CryG/). I have updated the details in the next answer.

Comment: Dear Soundar-r. Would you be upset if i disturb you again? IE doesn't show correctly, all child areas are about 40px left indent and about 20px hidden in bottom. Also Always visible area has 10px from top. Not sure how to fix it for IE. Thanks for your help again.

Comment: Hi yener, can you say which version of IE browser you have used.? and can you update a code snippet or fiddle to check your issue.. because i have tested in IE10, IE11 where it works fine..

Comment: Dear Soundar-r. I am terribly sorry for wrong alert. I figured it out. The problem was div width was not enough. So, i make enough room for div which inside of Parent div, now works excellent. Please forgive me for wrong alarm.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jquery - it's very easy.

HTML for simple accordion:

```
<div id="Accordion">
    <div>
        <div class="Title">Visible</div>
        <div class="Boxen">Hidden</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="Title">Visible</div>
        <div class="Boxen">Hidden</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Title {
    width:400px;
    height:30px;
    background-color:green;
}
.Boxen {
    width:400px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color:pink;
    display: none;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(".Title").hover(function () {
    $(this).next(".Boxen").slideToggle();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/56G83/2/)

EDIT: Updated fiddle to show simple accordion

Comment: you're very welcome.  Just fyi, I wrapped the pairs of divs with a containing div for readability purposes, they can be removed and you will still have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to hover a hidden element - there is nothing the `.hover()` can bind to.

`opacity` seems to be a solution - see e.g. this other Stack Exchange question, [Hover over a hidden element to show it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595311/hover-over-a-hidden-element-to-show-it)

Try this:

```
$('#hidden').on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(1,1);
    },mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(1,0);
    },click: function() {
        $(this).off('mouseleave');
    }
});
```

See [Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/56G83/1/) (spinoff from @fnostro). My source was [from here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/hover-and-click-functions-ignore-hover-once-clicked).

Comment: Thanks for reply (fnostro as well) however, my problem is there is about 20 items like <div id="item1"></div><div id="item2"></div><div id="item3"></div><div id="item4"></div>.... etc

Answer (score 0):

I have updated another [**Fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/soundar24/6CryG/) here, which is the most suitable structure for your application.

Here the any number of blocks can be added with the class name **`block`**. And each block should contain one **`parent`** element and **`child`** element. In parent put your title or summary and in child put your contents. You can also modify this structure as per your requirement.

Comment: you are great person. thank you so much again. I really appreciated for your help