# Using the jQuery .hover function

Tags: jquery, css, hover, visibility

I have some spans that I am trying to toggle the display of when the pointer hovers on them using jQuery and the CSS visibility property (display property is fine too, but neither has worked just far). The spans' code is as follows:

```css
.buy1 {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<span class="buy1">
  <h3><a href="#">buy</a></h3>
</span>
```

Likely the reason is that my jQuery is wrong, as it's not my strong suit. Anyone have a suggestion of something that would work better?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
 
    $( "span.buy1" ).hover(function() {
 
        $("span.buy1").css("visibility","visible");
 
    });
 
});
</script>
```

Comment: you want to display on hover and hide on mouse out right?

Answer (score 2):

how about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/7o6o65hw/)

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("span.buy1 a").hover(function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity" : "1"});
    }, function () {
        $(this).stop().animate({"opacity" : "0"});
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
.buy1 a{
    opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: Should have been accepted as the only working solution there :-)

Comment: This worked and looks amazing! Thank you! For the purposes of better UI, is there any way to amend this script such that the span displays when its parent element (a div, in this case) is hovered?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('span.buy1').hover(
        function () {
            $(this).show().stop().animate({
                left:'15px',
                opacity:'0.5'
            },500);  
        }, 
        function () {
            $(this).hide().stop().animate({"opacity": "1"},5000);    
        }
    );
});
```

Try This..

Answer (score 0):

You can use do that on css

```
.buy1:hover {
    visibility: visible;
}

.buy1 {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Hover over a hidden element to show it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595311/hover-over-a-hidden-element-to-show-it) for a similar question. Basically, you can accomplish this by setting opacity to 0, and jQuery's fadeTo method or really any other way of adjusting opacity.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
 
    $( "span.buy1" ).hover(function() {
        $("span.buy1").fadeTo(1,1);
 
    }, function() {
        $("span.buy1").fadeTo(1,0);  
    });
 
});
```

```css
.buy1 {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="buy1">
  <h3><a href="#">buy</a></h3>
</span>
```